# [[{{node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3286] error in the ai program

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

i am try to make python3 ai thing for predicting lstm; it gives error.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

# Define the model
model = keras.Sequential()

# Add an Embedding layer expecting input vocab of size 25149772, and output embedding dimension of size 64.
model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=128, output_dim=64))

# Add a LSTM layer with 25149772 internal units.
model.add(layers.LSTM(128))

# Add a Dense layer with 25149772.
model.add(layers.Dense(128))

model.summary()

df = pd.read_csv('model.mdl/data.csv')
df['Adjustments'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Adjustments']) + MonthEnd(1)
df = df.drop('Adjustments', axis=1)
df.head()

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)

train.to_csv('model.mdl/train.csv', index=False)
test.to_csv('model.mdl/test.csv', index=False)

train_df = pd.read_csv('model.mdl/train.csv')

X_train = train_df.drop('Unadjusted', axis=1)
y_train = train_df['Unadjusted']

#METHOD='binary_crossentropy'
METHOD='mean_squared_error'

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)

test_df = pd.read_csv('model/test.csv')

X_test = test_df.drop('Unadjusted', axis=1)
y_test = test_df['Unadjusted']

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print('Model accuracy:', accuracy)
```

expected results: The program will build the AI model and run the AI model. The program will tell you the AI model's accuracy at predicting what the next entry would be.

actual results:
2023-12-01 17:43:26.511003: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2023-12-01 17:43:26.511083: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2023-12-01 17:43:26.542704: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2023-12-01 17:43:26.612227: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-12-01 17:43:27.834358: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2023-12-01 17:43:29.626410: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-12-01 17:43:29.748310: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2256] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
Model: "sequential"

---

## Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #

embedding (Embedding)       (None, None, 64)          8192

lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 128)               98816

dense (Dense)               (None, 128)               16512

=================================================================
Total params: 123520 (482.50 KB)
Trainable params: 123520 (482.50 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)

---

/home/linux/Documents/./rnn.py:26: UserWarning: Could not infer format, so each element will be parsed individually, falling back to `dateutil`. To ensure parsing is consistent and as-expected, please specify a format.
df['Adjustments'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Adjustments']) + MonthEnd(1)
Epoch 1/10
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/linux/Documents/./rnn.py", line 44, in 
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup defined at (most recent call last):
File "/home/linux/Documents/./rnn.py", line 44, in

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1807, in fit

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1150, in train_step

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 590, in **call**

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py", line 1149, in **call**

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/sequential.py", line 398, in call

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py", line 515, in call

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py", line 672, in _run_internal_graph

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py", line 1149, in **call**

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler

File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/core/embedding.py", line 272, in call

indices[0,0] = 15349625 is not in [0, 128)
[[{{node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3286]

im am dum